# AngularJS - $http interceptor - alter response data

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to modify the `data` property of the `response` object? I've tried with:

```
function interceptor() {
    return {
        response: function (response) {
            response.data = response.data.xyz;
            return response;    
        }
    };
}
```

Needless to say, it didn't work. There's no error, nothing in the console and all I get is a blank page.

Comment: Have you added `$httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptor);` after that?

Comment: Yeah, the other parts of the interceptor are working fine. It's just going full blank when I add the response part.

Comment: Actually, it modifies the `data`property, but for some reason it doesn't load the template after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was the `xyz` property didn't always exist and it silently failed. Checking whether the property exists makes everything work.

Comment: Please mark your own answer as the accepted answer so every other user in SO knows this is a closed question.